# How do you access react-id-swiper active slide ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

Is anyone familiar with react-id-swiper (based on Swiper) that can tell me how to access the currentSlideId? I'm trying to create a reference to the active slide in state.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-id-swiper

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#initialize

So far the closest I've gotten is by installing Swiper instead of react-id-swiper now I can call .activeIndex but am still unsure how to use that to trigger a rerender.

```
componentDidMount() { 
    this.mySwiper = new Swiper(
        '.swiper-container', 
        { direction: 'vertical', slidesPerView: 1, spaceBetween: 0, speed: 1000, mousewheel: true, hashNavigation: true }
    ); 
this.mySwiper.on('slideChange', function() { console.log(this.mySwiper); }); }
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, do you have any code to share sharing what you've tried so far? [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So far the closest I've gotten is by installing Swiper instead of react-id-swiper now I can call .activeIndex but am still unsure how to use that to trigger a rerender.

Comment: `componentDidMount() {   
     this.mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {   
      direction: 'vertical',  
      slidesPerView: 1,  
      spaceBetween: 0,  
      speed: 1000,  
      mousewheel: true,  
      hashNavigation: true   
    });  
    this.mySwiper.on('slideChange', function() {
      console.log(this.mySwiper);
    });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by installing the Swiper library which react-id-swiper is based on. Swiper has a .currentSlideId function which can be called on the Swiper object.